# Beginner server local installation

Tags: email, exchange-2010

Here's the thing I own a small business and currently my emails are being managed by some regular hosting using cpanel and that

I bought a small server and installed windows server and exchange

Can you tell what I did wrong here

1. Installed and configured my current existing domain
2. Configured all email address
3. Installed noip in case my public address change
4. In the cpanel of the domain I've added an MX record to the noip domain of the server with priority 0 so now emails are being received by my own server

Now whenever I send an email to anyone gmail hotmail etc I get a response that cannot be delivered since may be junk

This didn't happen when I sent emails from the hosting

What's missing what did I do wrong

heres the code

```
mx.google.com rejected your message to the following e-mail addresses:
Joan J. Guerra Makaren (joanjgm23@gmail.com)
mx.google.com gave this error:
[186.88.202.13 12] Our system has detected that this message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for more information. cn9si815432vcb.71 - gsmtp 
Your message wasn't delivered due to a permission or security issue. It may have been rejected by a moderator, the address may only accept e-mail from certain senders, or another restriction may be preventing delivery.

Diagnostic information for administrators:
Generating server: SERVERMEGA.megaconstrucciones.com.ve
joanjgm23@gmail.com
mx.google.com #550-5.7.1 [186.88.202.13 12] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550 5.7.1 more information. cn9si815432vcb.71 - gsmtp ##
Original message headers:
Received: from SERVERMEGA.megaconstrucciones.com.ve
 ([fe80::9096:e9c2:405b:6112]) by SERVERMEGA.megaconstrucciones.com.ve
 ([fe80::9096:e9c2:405b:6112%10]) with mapi; Thu, 29 May 2014 11:32:19 -0430
From: prueba <prueba@megaconstrucciones.com.ve>
To: "Joan J. Guerra Makaren" <joanjgm23@gmail.com>
Subject: Probando correos
Thread-Topic: Probando correos
Thread-Index: Ac97V1eW4OBFmoqJTRGoD7IPTC2azg==
Date: Thu, 29 May 2014 16:04:35 +0000
Message-ID: <000f4249.4487966276f7b241@megaconstrucciones.com.ve>
Accept-Language: en-US, es-VE
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_000f42494487966276f7b241megaconstruccionescomve_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: `Can you tell what I did wrong here` - unfortunately, pretty much all of it.

Comment: You don't explain how you send e-mails. Did you configure a smart host in Exchange? I recommend that you use your CPanel server as smart-host, since office- and home-connections are often classified as spam. If you already do this, contact the company that manages the CPanel server, they should keep it off spam lists.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you host your mail server with your home or office's "dialup" internet connection (in other words, not hosted by some kind of hosting provider).

In that case it's highly likely the IP address is listed as such in databases that E-Mail servers use to protect themself from spam and they will always classify your mail as spam. There is nothing you can do about this - hosting E-Mail from home/small business internet connections simply doesn't work anymore (for a decade or two now).

The "best" you can hope to achieve in that case is to host a "second line" mail server at your office and use your current mail service to actually send/receive the mail.

Comment: It is also likely the OP ignored little beginner issues like a SPF entry or the proper HELO identification that matches the RDNS entry for the IP.... all the usual "I have no clue what I do, but do not want to pay for someone who knows" thingies.

Comment: @TomTom Indeed. Even though the cost of getting a small business plan for Office365 or GoogleApps is negligible when compared to operating the rest of a business.

Comment: For a small business looking for enterprise features, you really can't beat Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of hassle to go through when there are several services out there such as Office365 and Google Apps that will handle all the maintenance and storage for you.

While it's technically possible to go the route you've done, it's not necessarily the best decision.

- Google/Microsoft are well-known organizations that are not going to be as readily black-listed. Saving you time and energy.
- How much is time worth? If you're spending 10 hours/month managing your email solution, how much revenue and/or opportunity cost have you lost for your business in developing an email solution yourself?
- Supportability and Failure Recoverability. What happens to your business if you bought a set of drives that go bad? Is your order processing all in email? How do you know who paid for what if that's also stored in your email?

You need to think long-term about these things and consider what the real costs to your business are. If it's just 2-3 people in your business, there's no need to run a full email server. Services such as Google Apps and Office365 run in the US$5-15 per user-month range, and is a very small cost compared to costs such as inventory or salaries and benefits for staff.

If your business is large enough to run its own email service vs. the cost of an online service, consider hosting that email with a Managed Service Provider that operates out of a datacenter. This will provide with the MSP's expertise in hosting and connectivity, and you can still manage your own Email services.

Comment: Current solutions are not an option, trust me I wouldn't be asking if they were

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the full response?  Initial thoughts would be that the MX of your noip service may be blacklisted.

P.S.: if you're a small company, did you not consider Exchange Online?

Comment: Do you even know what's Que?

Answer (score 0):

No offense intended, but you seem to lack most of the knowledge needed to run Exchange, which is quite a complex product; you would probably be better off running a simpler mail server, or leaving the whole email business to your hosting provider. Or at least you should hire a consultant to set everything up.

Also, if you don't have at least a public, static IP address, running your own mail server is something you should avoid at all costs. Horrible kludges susch as noip don't really play well with mail delivery.

If you need the services Exchange provides in addition to simple mail delivery but can't/don't want to host your own mail server, you can also subscribe to [Exchange Online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/microsoft-exchange-online-for-business-work-smarter-anywhere-FX103739072.aspx). Microsoft will manage everything for you, and you'll be able to use the service without having to worry about setting it up and making it work.

Comment: Current solutions like Google or Microsoft are not an option, trust me I wouldn't be asking if they were

Comment: Well, then you should at least get a fixed public IP address, or you aren't going anywhere. That said, you have two options: either you spend a lot of time studying mail servers in general and Exchange specifically (as well as Windows Server and Active Directory), or you hire someone who knows what he's doing.

Comment: You can downvote all you want... it will not improve your chances of successfully running an Exchange server.

Comment: nobody is downvoting answers, im just saying that those are not options for my situation otherwise i wouldn't be asking @Massimo

Comment: Well, somebody *is* downvoting, votes don't just go down magically. Anyway, I repeat: if you really want/need to run your own mail server, you'll need a persistent Internet connection with a public static IP address; mail servers just don't work any other way. And Exchange *is* an astonishingly complex product, probably the most complex mail server out there; it takes a lot of skill to successfully manage it.

Comment: Well theres a lot of users not only the OP can vote, I didn't even know you can vote answers until you mention it, anyhow, im requesting fixed IP

Comment: Not only the static IP address, but the Reverse DNS lookup should be correct. This means you need to contact your ISP, who should be in control of the PTR records for the IP address you will have.